# Positioning nested table to right in cell

Tags: html, css

the best way to show you what I want to achive is showing the picture: 
[image]

I tried to position nested tables to each side of row. I looked for solution but didn't find anything interesting. 
When I played with "position: absolute;" i did more damage than good results. Is it possible to do it like in the picture?

EDIT: It's not my project and I don't have any influence on design. It's based on table and I have to deal with it :)

Answer (score 4):

you could float it.. <strike>or you could probably just have that cell holding it set to `text-align: right` depends on what else is in it the cell whether you need just the nested table to the right..</strike> (that doesn't work in all browsers)

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td>
    <table style="background: red;">
      <tr>
          <td>left</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td>
    <table style="background: green; float: right">
       <tr>
          <td>right</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have left it a few hours, but if the downvoter or downvote sympathiser wants to tell me why this is wrong or what's the difference between this and a later answer (without a down vote) - I will gladly delete or amend, in all  this is not helping the OP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use divs instead of table tags to contain the two, have a left and right div instead of your two TD tags like so:

```
<div class="left"><table></table></div>
<div class="right"><table></table></div>
```

Then just add some CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  .left, .right {
    width:300px;        
  }
  .left {
    float:left;
  }
  .left table, .right table {
     width:63%;
  }
  .right table {
    float:right;
  }
</style>
```

I would go that route as supposed to using tables. If it doesnt work though, you might need to change the display type of the td tags to block. That said, I haven't tried that before and I'm not sure how well it would work.

Comment: hmm... so I think I can do somethin like:
<td>
  <div class="left">
     <table id="nestedTableRight">...</table>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="right">
     <table id="nestedTableRight"> ... </table>
  </div>
</td> 

right?

Comment: I'm suggesting to avoid using tables to wrap the divs. Tables by default make it tricky to align things the way you want to. What are you using the table tags for?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any more content in the containing <td> you could float it to the right;

```
/* select nested tables in td's that have a preceding td sibling, effectively the second column */
table td + td table {
    float: right;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KkUUs/)

Answer (score -2):

Keep these notes in mind:

1. Absolute positioning and floated children cause **[Great Collapse](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/)**. So, your cell could get unpredictable for you.
2. Nested tables are not common these days. Maybe your design is wrong. Have you considered other designs. Maybe div elements inside a table cell, nesting a table inside a list item?
3. Table is a **block level element** in nature. That is, a table tries to fill its parent's width by default. So, to get to your result, you need to specify width for them.

My suggestion, keep far from tables. Use CSS positioning.

Comment: re: #1 - a table cell establishes a new block formatting context so there will be no collapse - a table cell will contain floats - re: #3 that is not correct, if you don't give your table a width it will shrink to fit. It's a table element and it's actually more like an `inline-block` in nature.

Comment: if it would be mine project I'd never use table layout... but it's "old school programmers" web app and I don't have any influence on that part... ;x hm, I can't check all answears now, but I'll try to do it tomorow and tell you about results. :)